# filtering string to keep a-z and space marks c++?

Tags: c++, string, qt

I'm using QT to design a dictionary to sort a word/string of words entered by a user.

In 'silent mode' I want the user to only enter a single word (a-z) or a string of words (a-z, separated by a space).

I'm really having trouble trying to filter out non-alphabetical while keeping whitespaces!

```
if(ui->silentButton->isChecked())
{
    if(userWord == " ") // if user enters just a space
    {
        QMessageBox messageBox;
        messageBox.critical(0,"Error!","Please enter a valid word to continue...");
        messageBox.setFixedSize(500,200);
    }
    else if(userWord == "") // if user enters nothing
    {
        QMessageBox messageBox;
        messageBox.critical(0,"Error!","Please enter a valid word to continue...");
        messageBox.setFixedSize(500,200);
    }

    else if (userWord.contains(" ")) // if user enters a string that contains a space
    {
        QStringList Splitstring = userWord.split(QRegExp("\\W"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);

        for(int i = 0; i < Splitstring.size(); ++i)
        {
            MyTree->insert(MyTree->getRoot(), Splitstring.at(i).toLocal8Bit().constData());
        }
    }

    else
    {
        MyTree->insert(MyTree->getRoot(),userWord);

    }
```

Unfortunately this does not work as it still allows the user to enter a non-alphabetical or a string containing a non-alphabetical i.e. `}` `a}` `a b c}`

I want it to bring up an error when they enter anything at all that is non alphabetical.  I have tried using `if(userWord.contains(QRegExp("\\w")))` however this also filters out spaces too.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ui->silentButton->isChecked())
{
    if(userWord.trimmed() == "") // if user enters just a space or nothing
    {
        QMessageBox messageBox;
        messageBox.critical(0,"Error!","Please enter a valid word to continue...");
        messageBox.setFixedSize(500,200);
    }
    else if (userWord.contains(" ")) // if user enters a string that contains a space
    {
        QStringList splitString { userWord.split(QRegularExpression("[^a-z]"), QString::SkipEmptyParts) };

        for(int i = 0; i < splitString.size(); ++i)
        {
            MyTree->insert(MyTree->getRoot(), splitString.at(i).toLocal8Bit().constData());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MyTree->insert(MyTree->getRoot(),userWord);
    }
}
```

This should do the trick for you.

I've made some improvements like adding `trimmed()` because that will make it work for both input errors, as well as specifying more than one space and adjusted the regular expression to exclude what you don't need.

I've replaced `QRegExp`, because `QRegularExpression` should be used instead as it is faster (new).

Variables should start with lowercase, therefore the `splitString` renaming.

Now the result for this input:
`"test          } awa} fa baad cdda c}"`

is:

`test
awa
fa
baad
cdda
c`

Answer (score 0):

As @deW1 pointed out you should be using [QRegularExpression](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html) for performance issues and try using this for regular expression

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+( )?[a-zA-Z]+)*$/
```

This will allow blank spaces separated values.